# Why does function return `outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation']`?

Tags: angular

Why does function below return `outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation']` rather than just `outlet.activatedRouteData['animation']`? (which is presumably the value we care about)?

`src/app/app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/enter-leave' },
      { path: 'open-close', component: OpenClosePageComponent },
      { path: 'status', component: StatusSliderPageComponent },
      { path: 'toggle', component: ToggleAnimationsPageComponent },
      { path: 'heroes', component: HeroListPageComponent, data: {animation: 'FilterPage'} },
      { path: 'hero-groups', component: HeroListGroupPageComponent },
      { path: 'enter-leave', component: HeroListEnterLeavePageComponent },
      { path: 'auto', component: HeroListAutoCalcPageComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: {animation: 'HomePage'} },
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: {animation: 'AboutPage'} },

    ])
  ],
```

`src/app/app.component.html`

```
<div [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)" >
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

`src/app/app.component.ts`

```
prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
  return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'];
}
```

Comment: This is returning a boolean. If you just said `return !!outlet.activatedRouteData['animation']` but `outlet` or `outlet.activatedRouteData` didn't exist, you'd get one of these errors: `Cannot read property [X] of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an attempt to avoid an error occurring. 
All values will have to be defined in order to get the correct return. otherwise a falsy value will be returned (undefined || null), but importantly, not an error leading to unwanted behaviour.

```
return outlet // if outlet is defined this will be fine.
```

Below, if outlet is falsy (undefined || null) it will return only outlet,
 this stops `activatedRouteData` being accessed which would lead to a TypeError error. Which could be seen in the browser console.

```
return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData
```

To continue that, as long as `outlet` is truthy (has a value in this case) it would return `outlet.activatedRouteData`. And so on, if `outlet.activatedRouteData` is truthy then `outlet.activatedRouteData['animation']` would be returned otherwise only  `outlet.activatedRouteData` would be returned.

To summerise this is checking that the left operand (value) has a truthy value in order to return the right operand (value). Leading to no TypeErrors trying to access attributes that are not defined.

```js
function example()
{
    return null && 3; // will return null. because left hand if falsy.
}
console.log(example());

function exampleTwo()
{
    return 3 && 6; // will return 6 (right hand) , because left value is truthy
}
console.log(exampleTwo());
```

Without the above logic you would likely see a TypeError occur similar to the following by trying to access an attribute that is not defined.

```js
function TypeError()
{
    let example;
    return example.test;
}

console.log(TypeError());
```